# breakpoint not being added blazor wasm project Visual Studio 2019 16.10.1 sdk 5.0.301

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, blazor, webassembly

I have blazor wasm application that has been working with the debugger for several months. This problem started yesterday. It is getting errors like on the ones below if I have breakpoints set in vs 2019 16.10.1 and I press f5 for debugging.
So When I have no breakpoints in the entire program the first page loads correctly.  When the first page loads (3 tiles on the page) it loads successful and then I set a breakpoint on another component( it gets two errors per one breakpoint).... it gets the error just by clicking the breakpoint in the VS 2019 source..(it is interactive) . It doesn't matter if I use iisexpress or kestrel. I've uninstalled vs 2019 and reloaded. (my thought was did I turn something on in vs 2019 that I dont want). . I've deleted .vs folder in the  solution of the project  thinking it is something in the solution . Suggestions are welcomed. I've report  this also (on the github.com/aspnetcore)
[image]

Comment: I've noticed exactly the same issue. I have a preview version of Visual Studio 2019 also installed. The preview version seemed to work with chrome based browsers The stable version of Visual Studio 2019 16.10.2 didn't work. So I tried the stable version but this time ran the server startup project from within visual studio and when chrome opened up I made sure the developer tools was open. It seemed to work not sure if it's required or not or a temporary problem. I also had to make sure to re-add the break points so they turn solid red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some help from microsoft on this. Currently, blazor wasm .net 5 does not allow embeded pdb so make sure it is set to the pdb to portable option in the solution.  [image]